# Rails Ecommerce Relationships

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, relational

Hey so I'm building out my backend for a ecommerce website

Currently I have my basic models set up but running into relationship issues

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shop
  has_many :transaction_items
  has_many :transactions, through: :transaction_items
  has_many :users, through: :transactions
end


class Shop < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items
  has_many :transactions, through: :items
  has_many :user_shops
  has_many :users, through: :user_shops
end

class TransactionItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :transaction
end

class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :shop, optional: true
  has_many :transaction_items
  has_many :items, through: :transaction_items
end

class UserShop < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shop
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :transactions
  has_many :items, through: :transactions
  has_many :user_shops
  has_many :shops, through: :user_shops
  has_secure_password

  validates :username, uniqueness: true
  validates :username, presence: true
end
```

Stories:
User signs up and is directed to home page
User clicks on a shop and is directed to shop page
User selects items from shop page and adds to shopping cart
User makes transaction and pays total for all items in shopping cart
Each shopping cart is unique to that store page (can't combine items from different stores into one shopping cart)

So I want a User to have many Items through transactions (User obtains items after making transaction in checkout)

but should I be using Items has many users through transactions or Items have many users? Confused in this decision because transactions only belongs to users

Or a completely alternative approach

Should I make a new join model user_items (join table) not related to transactions between users and items such as user_items or would the current set up work better? Since users should only be able to have items if a transaction is made

I wanted to make less models to start off so things wouldn't get too complicated but my transaction model is already confusing me a bit

I appreciate any help or advice! Excited to get past this phase so I can start building.

Comment: Read more about Database normalization/denormalization

Comment: It may help to give your associations and JOINS models mode descriptive names. For example, `UserShop` could be `ShopMembership`; `TransactionItem` could be `Sale`; each `Item` could `has_many :buyers` (instead of `:users`); each `Shop` could `has_many :customers` (instead of `:users`); ... I don't see anything particularly wrong with your model, it's the use of such generic names that's a bit confusing.

Comment: I apologize. I can definitely see this being frustrating to read/understand. I just don't want to give them definite names like those because i don't know if they're going to follow the purpose of "membership" or "sale" at the moment. I'll try and improve the naming in time!

Comment: @VijayRaju, without knowing your project, auditorium, size, not a possible to choice true statement from two workable. Standard way `has many users through transactions`.

Comment: @Leo. Got it, I'll keep this for now then. I just wanted to make sure this would work since Transactions belongs to User and not has many Users. So Items can still have many users through a model that belongs to users?